# Can't append rest of string after closing php tags and process php data inside html tags

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to send mail to a user where it outputs patient name and hospital name hyperlinked to its location(present inside the database). The message body variable takes only upto the string hospital name and doesn't append the name of the hospital hyperlinked to its location on the map. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
    //Take contents of the search box
if($name=file_get_contents('file.txt')) {   //create a temp file in bloodonation and take the name from there,then delete the temp file
    $multiple= explode(',',$name);
    $firstname = $multiple[0]; // firstname                                                                                                   
    $fathername = $multiple[1]; // fathername
    $lastname = $multiple[2]; // lastname    
    unlink('file.txt'); 
    $query ="SELECT email
        FROM personprofile
        WHERE   firstname= '$firstname' AND lastname= '$lastname' AND fathername= '$fathername'";
        $fetchemail=  mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $process=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchemail);
        //mail function parameters, send two sets of messages depending on blood/organ donation
        // create a new paitent with the city beirut and check the mail results
        $to=$process['email'];
        $header= "Blood is urgently needed";
        $phquery="SELECT personprofile.firstname,personprofile.lastname,personprofile.fathername,hospital.hospitalname,hospital.geolocation 
        FROM personprofile,hospital,areaname 
        WHERE areaname.id= hospital.area AND personprofile.hospitaladmission= hospital.id AND areaname.area='$city'";
        $fetchospitalperson=  mysqli_query($link,$phquery);
        $processtable=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchospitalperson);
        $messagebody= "Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." ".$processtable['fathername']." ".$processtable['lastname']."  "."Hospital Name:" ?>
        <html><body>
        <a href="<?php $processtable['geolocation']?>" >
        <?php " ".$processtable['hospitalname'];?>
        </a></body></html> 
        <?php //Name of the person that needs the blood transfusion along with hospital he is staying at,hyperlinked to its location
        $message= "Dear"." ".$firstname." ".$lastname.",".PHP_EOL .$messagebody; 
    if(isset($sendtoperson)){   
        if(mail($to,$header,$message)){
            echo "Sent";
        }
        else{ echo "Not sent";}
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dear God, please tell me you are a student.

Comment: `<?php $processtable['geolocation']?>` won't do anything, you'd need to `echo` that.

Comment: no `echo()`, OP is about sending the HTML with `mail()` and the contents should be in `$message`.

Comment: This code is extremely insecure. Please read up on SQL Injection attacks before doing anything else with a database.

Comment: Read about [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples) to improve security!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $messagebodyA = "Patient Name: ".$processtable['firstname']." ";
    $messagebodyA .= $processtable['fathername']." ";
    $messagebodyA .= $processtable['lastname']." ";
    $messagebodyA .= "Hospital Name: ".$processtable['hospitalname'];

    $messagebody = "<html><body>";
    $messagebody .= '<a href="' .$processtable['geolocation']. '">'; // Note single quotes to allow double quotes in html tag
    $messagebody .= $processtable['hospitalname'];
    $messagebody .= "</a><br><br>";
    $messagebody .= "Dear ".$firstname." ".$lastname.",<br><br>".$messagebodyA;
    $messagebody .= "</body></html>";


    $message = $messagebody; // to be compliant with the rest of the code
?>
```

Comment: hey guys thanks for the help. The geolocation should be hyperlinked to hospital name extracted from the database